# How to keep a var to never ask again terms and conditions

Tags: ios

I want to know how to keep the content of a var for example, I start my app for the first time I get the popup with the terms and conditions I accept so I modify acceptedTerms var to true but when I close the app the var will get this default state like false or true and the if condition will don't be used.

Comment: Multiple ways 1. Use UserDefaults. Set a variable in userDefault once user accepts terms and conditions. Every time you launch app check if variable exists in UserDefault if its not there prompt the alert else dont. Issue with this approach if user deletes the app n reinstalls then ull end up showing alert again

Comment: 2. Make use of keychain to save the state (same logic as before, but am not a very big fan of it anyway). Pros : Even if you reinstall because they will have same bundle id you will still be able to access it and your logic will work. Cons : If user installs app on different device and launch it for first time u would still be ended up showing alert. 3. Use a backend engine, have API to update the state of acceptance and every time user launches the app query the server and if present do not show uit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use `UserDefaults`.

When user accepts terms and conditions then you can set a `bool` flag to true.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isAccepted")
```

You can check that flat before showing the pop up.

```
let isAccepted = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isAccepted")
if !isAccepted {
    // show pop up here
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, resolved :)